# Why does cfn-init repond with this odd message?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have trouble getting cfn-init to work on Windows.

I do this:

```
cfn-init.exe -v -c config 
  -s arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-north-1:894422057177:stack/Providence-Core-A47K89HAVG6V/20f830c0-05cd-12ea-9527-06c34fc32621 
  -r MyHost  
  --region eu-north-1
```

(line breaks added for clarity)

and get as a result:

```
('Connection aborted.', error(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

What causes this error?  What is it that cannot be reached? (it is not the most verbose error message I've seen :-))

Is `cfn-init.exe` actually trying to access something on the network? If so, what target address?
My outbound rules are fairly restrictive both when it comes to Network ACL and SecurityGroup. They don't have general outbound access for http/https. Is that the reason?

Comment: are you trying to connect to some resource like RDS in your CFN template?

Comment: I wonder if the instance does not have connectivity to the Internet? Is it in a private subnet? Is the Security Group blocking outbound access?

Comment: Yes, my Security Group is (deliberately) blocking outbound access, except to the S3 Endpoint needed by the components *within* the init section.I can verify that this indeed works from a browser on same host. To be honest it seems to me that the `cfn-init.exe` needs to fetch the CloudFormation stack from somewhere (the `-s` argument) and this is what fails. But I don't want to randomly just open up for outbound access.

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line: yes, the `cfn-init` command indeed does an outbound https request. Your SecurityGroup, Subnet ACLs, etc, must allow this.

The `cfn-init` command attempts to download the relevant CloudFormation stack from the [AWS CloudFormation endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cfn_region) which is on Public Internet. Therefore, if the cfn-init feature is used, the EC2 instance *must* have outbound access to such endpoint.

If you don't want to grant generic outbound access for your EC2 instance then Amazon offers a [VPC Endpoint for the AWS CloudFormation service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-vpce-bucketnames.html).